# i'm using firebase to authenticate my phone no. can i customize the otp to 4 digits?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sms

I'm using firebase to authenticate my phone no. can I customize the OTP to 4 digits ? I searched many sites but they are telling there is no way for this.. what is your take on that can u help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many sites are correct - you can't choose the verification code.

Comment: Why is this an answer and not a comment? To me it looks like a comment so I'm confused

Comment: @TheGrandJ The OP asked if the "many sites" they consulted are saying it's not possible.  I confirmed those many sites are correct.  This becomes one more site that makes the claim!